# Remove color from widget form in QGIS

Tags: qgis, widget, qgis-widget

I used colors in a form widget, but I found out that this is not compatible with dark mode. So, I would like to reset this setting, but I don't know how. Is that function just missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function was introduced in more recent versions of QGIS: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/50803

[image]